# Why only hex recognized but not octal and byte if the left hand operand is a number in an expression

Tags: php

First expression:

displays 123 octal, is not recognized, if recognized it should be 83

Second Expression:

displays 291, here hex recognized, if not recognized it should be 123

Third Expression:

Displays 0

```
$y = 0+"0123";
echo $y;   


echo '<br>';
$x = 0+"0x123";
echo $x;  


echo '<br>';
$x = 0+"0b10101";
echo $x;  // This displays 0
```

output:

```
123
291
0
```

Comment: What you say it displays and what you say it "output" are different…?!

Comment: So is it 83 or 123? You contradict yourself.

Comment: It actually behaves differently in different versions, weeeeee… https://3v4l.org/ab3oH

Comment: Start PHP 7.1 two of the 3 above cases will fail and the first one will not be octal (in any version)

Comment: In PHP 7.2 your expressions will throw a warning

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.strings

Comment: @deceze  i edited my question. I have mistakenly shown wrong ouput.. I was checking it

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev i edited my question. I have mistakenly shown wrong ouput.. I was checking it

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

There is no mention of non-decimal support.

Answer (score 0):

PHP casting of strings to numbers is limited (and probably with good reason). If you want to use different base numbers you need to specify them as numbers e.g.

```
$y = 0123;
echo $y;   // 83        
$x = 0x123;
echo $x;  // 291
$x = 0b10101;
echo $x; // 21
```

Notice that they are not quoted.

If you want to explicitly convert strings you need to do the following:

```
echo octdec("0123"); // 83
echo hexdec("0x123"); // 291
echo bindec("0b10101"); // 21
```

The prefixes (e.g. `0` or `0x` or `0b`) are allowed but optional when using these functions.

Note: PHP used to support implicit casting of hex strings as numbers but as of 7.0 it does not